# How to use SERIAL_NUMBER time in Google Sheets API for Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the Google Sheets API to return the SERIAL_NUMBER time for dates in a spreadsheet I'm getting with Python 3. Here is the code that I'm using to get it (not including the credentials function:

```
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
'version=v4')
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

spreadsheetId = 'REDACTED'
rangeNames = ['Sheet1!A2:E','Sheet1!F2:F']
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=rangeNames, dateTimeRenderOption='SERIAL_NUMBER').execute()
print(result.get('valueRanges'))
```

As you can see, I am passing it the dateTimeRenderOption, however it always returns a formatted string, like '9/7/2016' instead of a serial number. How do I get the serial number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look into [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values), it's  noted that

> **`dateTimeRenderOption`** is only used if the **`valueRenderOption` is not `FORMATTED_VALUE`**.

Please also try adding [`ValueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption), with values `UNFORMATTED_VALUE` or `FORMULA`, into your code to determine how values should be rendered in the output.